# Compare all values from one table against a reference table and flag matches as '1' else '0'

Tags: sql

I need to create a reference table that is easy to update - call it REF table.

Then I need to compare values from a column in a different table - call it OTHER table - against values in the REF table.

Then, ideally, use a CASE WHEN statement such that where values from OTHER match values from REF then 1 else 0.

I've searched online, including this site for a while now and can't find exactly what I need, there are answers where only matching values are returned but I need to return all values and flag correct one as 1 and incorrect as 0.

Maybe I'm not wording my search very well as I'm new to this.

Comment: Please attach some data.. this is unclear question

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` plus `CASE WHEN col IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`?

Comment: Add sample table data (for both tables), and the expected result.

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (To avoid more product specific answers, before knowing the dbms.)

Answer (score 0):

Use a left join and a case? I assume that there is a field that can be joined

eg

```
select T1.ColA, case when T2.ColA is not null then 1 else 0 end as T2Match
from Table1 T1
left join Table2 T2
  on T1.ColA = T2.ColA
```

or a case when exists

```
select T1.ColA, 
       case 
           when exists (select T2.ColA from Table2 where T1.ColA = T2.ColA) then 1 
       else 0 end as T2Match
from Table1 T1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, use a corelated subquery.

```
SELECT OTHER.Column, ISNULL((select MAX(1) from REF  WHERE REF.Column=OTHER.Column),0) ExistInRef
FROM OTHER
```

Comment: ISNULL is a product specific function - for which dbms? (Question has no dbms tagged.)

Comment: That's much better!